# Unexpected invocation :remove_method (mocha)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am trying to test my Smser class in a rails application, and trying to use mocha to stub the actual sending method only. I should mention also that this is my first attempt at mocking/stubbing.

When running the test, I get the failure `unexpected invocation: :remove_method` - which looks like what mocha called on my object, to stub the method. So I am not sure what to do.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**Smser class**

```
# models/smser.rb
class Smser
  ...<truncated>...

  def self.instance
    @@instance ||= self.new
  end

  private

  # Need to stub this
  def twilio(args)
    @client.account.messages.create args
  end
end
```

**Test**

```
# test/models/smser.rb
test "should send sms" do
  Smser.instance.stubs(:twilio).with(from: '123', to: '234', body: 'Message body')
  # <- ... here we run something that should invoke 'twilio' on the Smser object
end
```

**Test Output**

```
unexpected invocation: 
  #<Smser:0x68e4940>.twilio(:from => '123', :to => :remove_method, :body => :twilio)

satisfied expectations:
- allowed any number of times, invoked once: 
  #<Smser:0x68e4940>.twilio(:from => '123', :to => '234', :body => 'Message body')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error practically means that Mocha is expecting different invocation of the `twilio` method on the `Smser` class.

Instead of:

```
Smser.instance.stubs(:twilio).with(from: '123', to: '234', body: 'Message body')
```

it should be:

```
Smser.instance.stubs(:twilio).with(from: '123', to: '234', body: :twilio)
```

because, as the error states, the body isn't "Message body" but `:twilio`.

HTH

Comment: I dont understand. I do NOT expect the body of that message to be :twilio. I expect it to be the body of my SMS message. And as can be seen by the second part of the output, it DID have also the correct invocation (you see it says "invoked once"). To my understanding, it is Mocha itself that made that extra call (to remove and override the stubbed method), and complained about it.... hows that for irony... :)

Comment: Well, in that case it means that the arguments that you are passing to the  method (which you are stubbing) are not what you expect them to be? I would suggest logging them out to STDOUT and comparing is everything working as you expect it to be.